# Count occurrences in strings of an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects called `results`,

Every object has a property called `ingredients`, which is a large string containing many ingredients,

I need to get the 5 most used occurrences,

For example with this array of objects :

```
"results": [
    {
      "title": "Monterey Turkey Omelet",
      "href": "http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Monterey-Turkey-Omelet/Detail.aspx",
      "ingredients": "butter, eggs, garlic, green pepper, monterey jack cheese, onions, turkey, water",
      "thumbnail": "http://img.recipepuppy.com/5506.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Canadian Bacon Omelet",
      "href": "http://www.recipezaar.com/Canadian-Bacon-Omelet-309202",
      "ingredients": "butter, canadian bacon, cheddar cheese, eggs, garlic, onions, potato, red pepper, sour cream",
      "thumbnail": ""
    }]
```

I need to get butter (2), garlic (2), eggs (2), onions (2), turkey (1)

Comment: Pls share what you have tried

Comment: @Hemant Halwai for now I just did results.map((r) => r.ingredients).join(",")) which allows me to get a big big string of all ingredients separed by a ,
Now I need to count all occurences and get the 5 most named

Comment: @HemantHalwai last update : results.map((r) => r.ingredients).join(",").split(","), now I have an array with all ingredients but I just need to keep the 5 most named !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Array.prototype.flatMap** ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)) is a good tool for creating aggregates over multiple objects.

```js
const results = [
{
  "title": "Monterey Turkey Omelet",
  "href": "http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Monterey-Turkey-Omelet/Detail.aspx",
  "ingredients": "butter, eggs, garlic, green pepper, monterey jack cheese, onions, turkey, water",
  "thumbnail": "http://img.recipepuppy.com/5506.jpg"
},
{
  "title": "Canadian Bacon Omelet",
  "href": "http://www.recipezaar.com/Canadian-Bacon-Omelet-309202",
  "ingredients": "butter, canadian bacon, cheddar cheese, eggs, garlic, onions, potato, red pepper, sour cream",
  "thumbnail": ""
}]

const wordCountMapReducer = function (wordCountMap, word) {
  if (wordCountMap.has(word)) {
    wordCountMap.set(word, wordCountMap.get(word) + 1)
  } else {
    wordCountMap.set(word, 1)
  }
  return wordCountMap
}

const countIngredients = results => [...results
  .flatMap(item => item.ingredients.split(', '))
  .reduce(wordCountMapReducer, new Map())
  .entries()
].sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
  .slice(0, 5)
  .map(([word, count]) => `${word} (${count})`)
  .join(', ')

console.log(
  countIngredients(results),
) // butter (2), eggs (2), garlic (2), onions (2), green pepper (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be something like that:

```
const result = {
  "results": [
    {
      "title": "Monterey Turkey Omelet",
      "href": "http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Monterey-Turkey-Omelet/Detail.aspx",
      "ingredients": "butter, eggs, garlic, green pepper, monterey jack cheese, onions, turkey, water",
      "thumbnail": "http://img.recipepuppy.com/5506.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Canadian Bacon Omelet",
      "href": "http://www.recipezaar.com/Canadian-Bacon-Omelet-309202",
      "ingredients": "butter, canadian bacon, cheddar cheese, eggs, garlic, onions, potato, red pepper, sour cream",
      "thumbnail": ""
    }]
};

const frequency = {};
result.results.forEach( result => {
  result.ingredients.split(", ").forEach( ingred => {
    if (!frequency[ingred]) {
      frequency[ingred] = 1;
    } else {
      frequency[ingred] += 1;
    }
  });
});
const topKeys = Object.keys(frequency).sort((a,b) => frequency[b]-frequency[a]).slice(0, 5);
topKeys.forEach( key => {
   console.log(key, frequency[key]);
});
```

Iterate over each item of your `results` array, split the `ingredients` and increment and `frequency` object according to what you find inside.
Then, sort the object key from bigger to smaller, take. the 5 first keys and retrieve their frequency from `frequency`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
let temp1 = results.map((r) => r.ingredients).join(",")).reduce((acc,curr)=>{
    
    curr.forEach(ing=>{ 
        acc[ing]?acc[ing]++:acc[ing]=1;
    })
    return acc;
},{})
```

that gives you an object like :

```
{
  "butter": 2,
  "eggs": 2,
  "garlic": 2,
  "green pepper": 1,
  "monterey jack cheese": 1,
  "onions": 2,
  "turkey": 1,
  "water": 1,
  "canadian bacon": 1,
  "cheddar cheese": 1,
  "potato": 1,
  "red pepper": 1,
  "sour cream": 1
}
```

then sort it like :

```
var sortable = [];
for (var ing in temp1) {
    sortable.push([ing, temp1[ing]]);
}

let final= sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
}).slice(0,5)
```

```js
let results = [{
    "title": "Monterey Turkey Omelet",
    "href": "http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Monterey-Turkey-Omelet/Detail.aspx",
    "ingredients": "butter, eggs, garlic, green pepper, monterey jack cheese, onions, turkey, water",
    "thumbnail": "http://img.recipepuppy.com/5506.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "Canadian Bacon Omelet",
    "href": "http://www.recipezaar.com/Canadian-Bacon-Omelet-309202",
    "ingredients": "butter, canadian bacon, cheddar cheese, eggs, garlic, onions, potato, red pepper, sour cream",
    "thumbnail": ""
  }
]

let temp1 = results.map(res=>res.ingredients.split(', ')).reduce((acc, curr) => {

  curr.forEach(ing => {
    acc[ing] ? acc[ing]++ : acc[ing] = 1;
  })
  return acc;
}, {})


var sortable = [];
for (var ing in temp1) {
  sortable.push([ing, temp1[ing]]);
}

let final = sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b[1] - a[1];
}).slice(0, 5);

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
var results = [
    {
      "title": "Monterey Turkey Omelet",
      "href": "http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Monterey-Turkey-Omelet/Detail.aspx",
      "ingredients": "butter, eggs, garlic, green pepper, monterey jack cheese, onions, turkey, water",
      "thumbnail": "http://img.recipepuppy.com/5506.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Canadian Bacon Omelet",
      "href": "http://www.recipezaar.com/Canadian-Bacon-Omelet-309202",
      "ingredients": "butter, canadian bacon, cheddar cheese, eggs, garlic, onions, potato, red pepper, sour cream",
      "thumbnail": ""
    }];
    var ingredients = [];
    for (index = 0; index < results.length; ++index) {
        ingredients.push(results[index]['ingredients'].split(','));
        
    }
    var merged = [].concat(...ingredients);
    var counts = {}; 
    merged.forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; });
    console.log(counts);
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ujh2e1a0/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Another not so efficient solution may be

```
let count = {}
results.forEach(obj => {
// you would need ingredients to be converted to an array
// you can use .join() here
    obj.ingredients.forEach(ingredient => {
        count[ingredient] = (count[ingredient] || 0) + 1
    }
}
```

Easier to understand, but it's a nested loop, so not too efficient. Maybe if your arrays are small these solution can be handy.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with such code:

```js
const results = [
    {
      "title": "Monterey Turkey Omelet",
      "href": "http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Monterey-Turkey-Omelet/Detail.aspx",
      "ingredients": "butter, eggs, garlic, green pepper, monterey jack cheese, onions, turkey, water",
      "thumbnail": "http://img.recipepuppy.com/5506.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Canadian Bacon Omelet",
      "href": "http://www.recipezaar.com/Canadian-Bacon-Omelet-309202",
      "ingredients": "butter, canadian bacon, cheddar cheese, eggs, garlic, onions, potato, red pepper, sour cream",
      "thumbnail": ""
    }];

const topIngridients = (data, top) => {
    const ingridients = Object.entries(data.reduce(
        (collector, item) => {
            return item.ingredients
                .split(',')
                .map(ing => ing.trim())
                .reduce((collector, ingredient) => {
                    collector[ingredient] = (collector[ingredient] || 0) + 1;
                    return collector;
                }, collector)
        }, 
        {}));
    ingridients.sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1]);
    return ingridients.slice(0, top);
}

console.log(topIngridients(results, 5));
```

Comment: No problem. Anyway, I like the solution with flatMap more, because it reduces the calls chaining, so the code becomes more readable.